# Is there a way to keep adding moving objects to the screen in JS?

Tags: javascript, sprite, setinterval

I am working on a simple game, like Crossy Road, where the player is a spaceship, and they have to cross a lane which contains other ships moving from top to down.  I've tried to use `setInterval()`, but that doesn't seem to. work, here is the link for the project in Code.org:

https://studio.code.org/projects/gamelab/mVC2Bqadlg-heWiFlPvrPX3D7AfH5Ty4EVbTAGLM3rE

I'll also include a snippet:

```js
/*
function randomAnimation() {
  var thing = createSprite(randomNumber(250,300),0);
  thing.velocityY = randomNumber(5,10);
  thing.velocityX = 0;
  thing.scale = 0.5;
  var randNumber = randomNumber(1,6);
  if (randNumber === 1) {
    thing.setAnimation("enemy1");
  } 
  else if (randNumber === 2) {
    thing.setAnimation("enemy2");
  } 
  else if (randNumber === 3) {
    thing.setAnimation("enemy3");
  } 
  else if (randNumber === 4) {
    thing.setAnimation("enemy4");
  } 
  else if (randNumber === 5) {
    thing.setAnimation("enemy5");
  } 
  else if (randNumber === 6) {
    thing.setAnimation("enemy6");
  }
}
*/

function draw() {
  background("white");
  setInterval(function() {
    var thing = createSprite(randomNumber(150, 300), 0);
    /*thing.velocityY = randomNumber(5,10);
    thing.velocityX = 0;
    thing.scale = 0.5;
    var randNumber = randomNumber(1,6);
    if (randNumber === 1) {
      thing.setAnimation("enemy1");
    } 
    else if (randNumber === 2) {
      thing.setAnimation("enemy2");
    } 
    else if (randNumber === 3) {
      thing.setAnimation("enemy3");
    } 
    else if (randNumber === 4) {
      thing.setAnimation("enemy4");
    } 
    else if (randNumber === 5) {
      thing.setAnimation("enemy5");
    } 
    else if (randNumber === 6) {
      thing.setAnimation("enemy6");
    }*/
    var enemies = createGroup();

  }, 2000);
  drawSprites();
}
```

As you can see, a lot of the code is commented, that is code that I tried using but didn't work as expected. The first bit of commented code is a function I created, I tried calling this function in a `setInterval()` outside of the `draw()` function, but that worked, creating a new ship every 2000ms, but they didn't have any velocity. I tried calling it in the. `draw()` function, but that caused one ship to appear every frame, which makes it impossible to cross said lane. I know that I need to use groups for this function, I just don't know how.

Also, there's an `if` statement which is used to randomly change the animation of the spawned sprites.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following approach:

```
// Create a group outside of any functions, so it's available to all of them.
var enemies = createGroup();

// Create a function that just builds a single enemy
function createEnemy() {
  // set velocity, scale, etc.
}

// In setInterval, create an enemy and add it to your group
setInterval(function() {
  var enemy = createEnemy();
  enemies.add(enemy);
}, 2000);


// A function to handle animation
function draw() {
  drawSprites();
}
```

I'm not familiar with the `studio.code.org` platform, so I'm not sure whether each sprite's animation should be initialized in `createEnemy()` or `draw()`. If it's in `draw()`, I see you have access to `group.setAnimationEach()`, which might be the way to go.

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestions in my code - here's the link: https://studio.code.org/projects/gamelab/mVC2Bqadlg-heWiFlPvrPX3D7AfH5Ty4EVbTAGLM3rE.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I put everything in the createEnemy() function and called it in setInterval. When I tried putting var enemy and enemies.add(enemy) in the setInterval, there was an error, likely due to the studio.code.org library. @SimonLutterbie

Comment: There's one more thing though, instead of having the ships appear at equal intervals, can you randomize the intervals. I tried doing this by setting the time value for the setInterval as random, but that doesn't work. I tried creating a separate setInterval, but that caused an error saying that the value is not a number. You should be able to see this when you run. the project in the link above. The error is in line 108 if you're wondering.